# nginx location directive using regular expression

Tags: regex, nginx, location, directive

I am using nginx location directive in order to access an url, as below:

https://myhost/something/staticpath/

In the above path, 'something' can be any value (dynamic) or it can be empty also.

I tried with the below location directive:

```
location ~ ^/(.*/)staticpath/ {
      index  index.html index.htm;
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
}
```

But this is not working as expected.
Can someone tell me what is the correct regular expression, I need to use here?

Comment: You need `?` after the group to make it optional.

Comment: Or just use `location ~ /staticpath/`